# My node server is crashing with TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the following error and my node server is crashing due it. The server restarts working properly as every time I reload the page.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at C:\Users\S\Desktop\insta\back\server.js:43:24
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\S\Desktop\insta\back\node_modules\mongoose\li
b\model.js:3800:16)
    at C:\Users\S\Desktop\insta\back\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
    at C:\Users\S\Desktop\insta\back\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Do you have any suggestion to handle it out?

Comment: Well, what's on line 43 of server.js?

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to convert undefined or null to an object in `server.js` on line 43.

Comment: I reformatted you question body, changed the title and removed one unrelated tag. Please provide source code because this question is too generic. We need details to solve problems.